# Laravel get sum in polymorphic many to many

Tags: laravel

I'd like to get the sum of a column of a polymorphic many to many relationship. So let's say you have a Post and a Comment model with that relationship, this doesn't work:

```php
$posts = Post::withCount([
  'comments as comments_priority_sum' => function ($q) {
    $q->sum('comments.priority');
  },
  ])
  ->orderBy('title', 'asc')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of laravel 8.x, we also have the [withSum()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) method, so you could simply do:

```
Post::withSum('comments', 'priority')->get();
```

And you would get a comments_sum_priority field in each instance of the Post model.

---

For older versions you can use a raw expression:

```
Post::withCount(['comments as comments_sum_priority' => function($query) {     
    $query->select(DB::raw('sum(priority)')); 
}])->get()
```

Just to clarify, your query doesn't work because the query builder's [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates) aggregate executes the query.